# How to manage Wildfly-embedded HornetQ with jconsole?

Tags: jmx, hornetq, wildfly, jconsole

I am running HornetQ inside Wildfly. I want to monitor/manage messages with Jconsole locally, however when I open Jconsole I don't see a process for HornetQ and when I tried the different Wildfly processes listed, there are no HornetQ beans listed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by running Wildfly's own Jconsole version (found in WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jconsole.bat (or .sh).